# Italic on first 2 words of datatable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatable

I'm making an academic bibliography table on my django website. On the second column of my datatable the first two words need to be in italic! How can I do this?

[image: it should be something like this:]

EDIT: I already added the class "italic" to the second row `<td>` for easy targeting.

How I got it working:

```
//call the function on every table update:
 $('#bibs').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    italic();
} );
//append class "italic" to second column
 "columnDefs": [ 
            { className: "italic", "targets": [2 ] },
    ],
//loop that split by space>transforms element 0 and 1 to italic>joins with space together
function italic() {
      var italicTd = document.querySelectorAll("td.italic");

      for(var i = 0, ii = italicTd.length; i < ii; i++) {
        td = italicTd[i].innerHTML;
        splitStr = td.split(" ");
        splitStr[0] = splitStr[0].italics();
        splitStr[1] = splitStr[1].italics();
        italicTd[i].innerHTML= splitStr.join(" ");
      }
};
```

Comment: One way to do this is to use a DataTables [column renderer](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) - specifically, by using a render function: `render( data, type, row, meta ) {...}`. That gives you access to the data in each cell of a column, and you can customize that data however you wish. There are examples in the official documentation and many questions also on Stack Overflow with more examples.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit @Marc, i'm hyped to become part of this marvelous community!